# How to Inner join two anonymous tables [SQL]

Tags: sql, join, anonymous

as the title states, Let's say i have three tables: `person`, `autos`, `numbers`.

*Created*

`First table` with: `INNER JOIN` of `person` and `autos`

`Second Table` with: `INNER JOIN` of `autos` and `numbers`

**Question:** Is it possible to `INNER JOIN` `first` and `second` `table` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two tables based on the `autos` part. Assuming it has an ID:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   first_table f
JOIN   second_table s ON f.auto_id = s.auto_id
```

Comment: The thing is, i do want to join it all together in one go, `first table` and `second table` was figurativly, it means i did first inner join along the lines of `Select * FROM "person" p INNER JOIN "autos" a on p."personID" = a."personID"` by doing this i created first table then i want to joint all this above with another collection of `inner join`'s that create the second table. Issue: since the table is only figuratevly, there should be some sort of anonymous way of `joining `

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 joins (with 3 tables) together. Which are the keys for the joins? `personID` for `person` and `autos` and on `numbers`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM person p
JOIN autos a ON p.keyA= a.keyA
JOIN numbers n ON a.keyB = n.keyB
```

Where `keyA` and `keyB` are the corresponding field on which you want to do the join.